# How to read files from every zip folder present in a directory

Tags: python, zip

I have lots of zip files in a folder, say the folder contains 1.zip, 2.zip, 3.zip etc.
Each of these zip folder contains many files. But each of them contains a file named ans.txt.
Now the ans.txt have format like:
Name= Devesh
Marks= 20
Age= 23
RollNo.= 34343
.
.
.
I want to know the name of the zip file that contains marks or age or any attribute entered by the user.
I have the written the following code:

```
    import os
    import glob
    import zipfile
    flag=0
    for zip_name in glob.glob('[0-9].zip'):
        z=zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name,"r")
        with z.open('BAND_META.txt') as f:
            for line in f:
                for word in line.split('='):
                    word=word.strip()
                    if flag==0
                        if word=="Marks"
                            flag=1# flag is intialised as 0
                    elif flag==1
                        if word==marks:#marks is entered by user.
                            print zipfile_name
                            flag=0
```

Now the program is only able to run for only one zip file say 1.zip, it is not going to 2.zip or 3.zip.

Please help.

Comment: It's because of your indentation. your `for` loop is at the same level as your `z = zipfile....` and `with open()...`

Comment: @Will I would say that is because of the the way the website asks us to format the code. If the code was just like this then I guess it wouldn't even run (It would throw an "Expected Indent" Error).

Comment: The posted code would currently raise a syntax error due to the incorrect indentation immediately following the `for` statement. Please post the actual code you are trying to run.

Comment: I just noticed that the code checks for the value of "flag" before defining it. Are you giving us your entire code?

Comment: As user1790813 said the for is not at the same level as while loop...That was my mistake sorry about that. It has been corrected now. And forgot to define the variable flag earlier so i mentioned in the comment that it was both intitalised and defined zero. But i will correct it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
import os
import zipfile

zipfiles = [z for z in os.listdir('.') if z.endswith('.zip')]


for zfile in zipfiles:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zfile) as z:
        with z.open('ans.txt') as f:
            if b'marks=' in f.read().lower():
                print(z.filename)
```

Comment: I tried to run your code but it is still not working. The same problem is persisting the code runs for 1.zip but it is not running for 2.zip.....And I have modified the problem a little bit so please read it.